Interaction between two dlopen() calls seg faults on linux due to libc/libgcc_s mismatch
I'm attempting to package up some software that was built on RedHat 7 and run on RedHat 8. I'm including some libraries such as glibc and libgcc_s along with the binary. The problem occurs when the RH8 host has /etc/nsswitch.conf configured to use "systemd". This will attempt to load the system installed libnss_systemd.so.2 and will seg fault later when pthread_cancel() is called.
The minimum reproducible example is:
int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
  dlopen( "libnss_systemd.so.2", RTLD_NOW );
  dlopen( "libgcc_s.so.1", RTLD_NOW );
  return 0;
}

Here the first dlopen() call fails with: GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /lib64/libnss_systemd.so.2). The second call seg faults inside do_dlopen().
My question is what exactly is happening here? libnss_ssystemd.so.2 depends on libgcc_s.so.1, so I assume the first dlopen() call is partially or incorrectly loading libgcc_s. What is the correct way to handle this case? Both of these dlopen() calls are in third party code I have no control over. Is it possible to convince libnss to ignore systemd somehow? I don't have permission to modify /etc/nsswitch.conf. I also don't have a version of libnss_systemd.so.2 from RH7 that I can include in the package.


I'm including some libraries such as glibc and libgcc_s along with the binary

Don't do that. This answer explains why using non-system GLIBC doesn't work.
Running software built on RedHat 7 on a RedHat 8 system should just work(TM) without copying any system libraries from RH-7.

So far it's been working on all supported platforms because we do package up the entire set of required libraries, including ld-linux.so. The install should be fully self contained and work across a wide range of kernels, including RH6. Using the system glibc doesn't work on all platforms, which is the reason for packaging it this way. The problem is that dependencies loaded through dlopen() such as those pulled in dynamically by libnss don't show up with "ld", so the packaging script isn't aware of these. And I don't have the RH7 libnss_systemd.so.2 to include anyway.

@FrankGennari -- "So far it's been working ..." -- well, not anymore. You are doing it wrong, playing "russian roulette", and the gun had just went off. The right way to solve this problem is to build (in a chroot, or a docker container) with the lowest version of GLIBC you want to support. "The install should be fully self contained" -- that is an impossible goal if you want to use dynamic linking.

The build environment is setup for other tools that interact with ours and fixed to a particular image that I have no control over. The problem is that we're trying to support older OSes than the other tools because some customers have not yet migrated. Maybe there's no way to do this correctly with the constraints I have. I wasn't even aware that dlopen() was being called from libnss until this problem came up.
